# Clarify the "communication" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

There is currently no wiki or more detailed information about [communication](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication). I'd like to resolve that, so it's more clear when it should be used.

- What is "communication"?
- Is this used for:

  - parent-parent ("My spouse and I disagree about how to raise our child")
  - child-parent ("How can I encourage my child to talk to me")
  - parent-child ("I can't get my child to understand why this is important")
  - all of the above? something else?

Answer (score 2):

After having paged through some of the questions with the tag, here are my thoughts.

Communication is the process by which people convey their ideas, thoughts, feelings and values so as to be understood by others.  Within the scope of Parenting.SE this includes communication between family members of any generation, parents to children, children to parents, parents to in-laws, spouse to spouse, etc.  This tag should be used for asking about how to explain something to another family member or for help in understanding what another family member is saying to you<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>[1](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/574/does-anyone-recognize-where-the-phrase-dinosaur-on-the-button-comes-from)</sup> Because sometimes we all [need help understanding toddlers](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/574/does-anyone-recognize-where-the-phrase-dinosaur-on-the-button-comes-from).

Answer (score 1):

After reading through many of the [tag;communication] questions because of a different meta question, I would propose a change to Becuzz's wording:

> Communication is about helping people understand one another and their thoughts, feelings or values. Within the scope of this website, this includes communication between family members as it relates to parenting or people involved in the development of your children, such as educators, physicians and care-providers.

What I've change is:

1. The wording of the initial sentence, so the on-hover pop-up on the tag is a little more useful.
2. The scope to include communication questions about talking to doctors, teachers, babysitters, mentors, etc.

Comment: I haven't actually made the wiki edit proposal yet, I'll wait for voting on this.